# NSFileSystemSize return factory memory size on iOS 10.3+ - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Since the release of iOS 10.3 and APFS for iPhone, getting the device memory size with :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
NSUInteger totalDeviceSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
NSUInteger totalDeviceFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
```

return the factory memory size. For example, on iOS 10.2, I got 11,60 Go for a 16 Go device. On 10.3+ I get 15,99 Go (result formatted with `stringFromByteCount`).

How could I do to restore the old behaviour ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

You might get total space and free space in this way:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *mypath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[mypath lastObject] error: &error];
NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [myDictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [myDictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
uint64_t totalSpaceSize = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
uint64_t totalFreeSpaceSize = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Comment: No you didn't use NSFileSystemFreeSize. what you used is NSFileSystemSize, I wrote both of them to show you the difference,

Comment: NSFileSystemFreeSize give you the space available on your device. What I would like to retrieve is the total space the device can have after the disk has been formatted, like when you just got your phone from Apple. this is what NSFileSystemSize did before iOS 10.3

Answer (score 0):

So it appear that it's now the desired comportment (tested in iOS 10.3, 10.3.1, 10.3.2 and iOS 11 beta 1 & 2).
To adjust the result depending on the installed iOS versions I do :

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion ios10_3 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){10, 3, 0};


if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios10_3]) {

    //User have at least 10.3 installed

}else {

    //below iOS 10.3

}
```